# Show that $\left|\left|\frac{d\hat{v}}{dt}\right|\right| = \frac{a\cdot\sin(\theta)}{s}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

As the title states, I'm trying to show that 
$$\left|\left|\frac{d\hat{v}}{dt}\right|\right| = \frac{a\cdot\sin(\theta)}{s},
$$
where

$\hat{v}$ is the unit velocity vector of a particle

$a = \left|\left|\vec{a}\right|\right| = $ the magnitude of the acceleration vector

$s = \left|\left|\vec{v}\right|\right| = $ the magnitude of the velocity vector

$\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{a}$.

I've been trying a wide variety of manipulations but the closest I've come is with:

$\left|\left|\frac{d\hat{v}}{dt}\right|\right| = \frac{a\sqrt{\cos(\theta)}}{s}$. But here, $\theta$ represents the angle between the acceleration vector and itself... Plus there's the square root.

Any thoughts on this?

Thank you very much for your time,

Eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The acceleration is defined as
$$ \mathbf{a} = \frac{d \mathbf{v}}{dt}$$
and the unit norm vector as $$ \hat{\mathbf v} = \frac{\mathbf{v}}{|\mathbf{v}|}=\frac{\mathbf{v}}
{\sqrt{\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{v}}}$$
Now the task is to calculate $|d\hat{\mathbf v}/dt|.$

We have with the chain rule
$$\frac{d \hat{\mathbf v}}{dt}
= |\mathbf{v}|^{-1}\mathbf{a} +\mathbf{v} \frac{d}{dt}(\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf{v})^{-1/2}
= \frac{\mathbf{a}}{|\mathbf{v}|} - \frac{\mathbf{v}}{|\mathbf v|^3}
\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{a}.$$
We additionally know that $\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{a} =|\mathbf v| \,|\mathbf a| \cos\theta$. We obtain 
$$ \frac{d \hat{\mathbf v}}{dt} \cdot  \frac{d \hat{\mathbf v}}{dt}
=\frac{|\mathbf{a}|^2}{|\mathbf{v}|^2}
+ \frac{|\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{a}|^2}{|\mathbf{v}|^4}- 2 \frac{|\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{a}|^2}{|\mathbf{v}|^4} =\frac{|\mathbf a|^2}{|\mathbf v|^2} - \frac{|\mathbf a|^2 \cos^2\theta}{|\mathbf v|^2} = \frac{|\mathbf a|^2 \sin^2\theta}{|\mathbf v|^2} ,$$
from which the result follows (with $|\sin \theta|$).